# how to change QComboBox text background color when mouse hover it(QSS)?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I need to change QComboBox background to red when mouse hover it;but in my qss style the QComboBox `drop-down` button change to red and the drop-down look like stranged(need to keep system default), it's look like raised style, that is not i wanted.

The simple qss style is:

```
QComboBox:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

---

**It looks like this when i try.**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        sheets = [str(i) for i in range(1, 10)]  

        combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        combo.addItems(sheets)                             

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(combo)
        self.setLayout(layout)


StyleSheet = """ 
QComboBox {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 1px 18px 1px 3px;
    min-width: 6em;
}
QComboBox:hover {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
}

"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: The drop-down button look like raised(need to keep flat) and how can i hover sub-items not to change it's color to red?